# Converting an executable file into an analog waveform signal

Tags: voice-recognition, voice

I have been trying to convert a digital binary file (.exe) into waveform to listen the resulted audio. I have been looking for any possible software/open source code to help me in achieving this, but no use.

My ultimate goal is to represent the .exe file as a spectogram to analyse the behaviour of the frequencies in the executable file. My understanding that I have to identify the range of frequencies first, which could be done by plotting the waveform first.

Any reference would be appreciated.

Edit:

I have a collection of binary files and I need to classify them according to their sound statistical features (frequency behaviour). My plan was to get the waveform of the actual binary file (by dividing the file into 1 signed byte each) and then convert the waveform into spectrogram picture and apply deep learning analysis for voice recognition

So, the depth of each sample will be 8-bits, and the sampling rate will be either 8Khz or 16 Khz. But I am confused of how to determine the frequencies related from the executable file

Comment: Since a binary is only 1s and 0s, it’ll sound like static. So what are you exactly trying to archive here?

Comment: Can you clarify how you intend to map the file byte values to audio values? Just byte by byte to represent PCM (pulse code modulation) values? I'm curious if you can use ffmpeg or sox to just force headers into the file (you'd need to set an arbitrary sample rate, at least). Going a little more manual you could read in the bytes directly in almost any language. E.g. in python, open(file, 'rb') will open the file for binary reading, and the returned file object has various methods to read in byte values.

Comment: @anonjnr: wav, mp3, ogg, etc files are also 1s and 0s. It's only to sounds pleasant, but depending on what the file structure looks like (is there repeated byte code? Any cadence or patterns?) it may actually have an interesting sound. Think dial up modem sounds -- not pleasant, but recognizable. Also, playing with the sample frequency might give even more interesting results.

Comment: Thanks for your response all. I have a collection of binary files and I need to classify them according to their sound statistical features (frequency behaviour). My plan was to get the waveform of the actual binary file (by dividing the file into 1 signed byte each) and then convert the waveform into spectrogram picture and apply deep learning analysis for voice recognition

Comment: So, the depth of each sample will be 8-bits, and the sampling rate will be either 8Khz or 16 Khz. But I am confused of how to determine the frequencies related from the executable file

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz got it, thanks!

Comment: I don't think voice recognition will work particularly well; built models are pretty tuned to relevant physical features such as vowel formant that you will absolutely not find in your binary files. The NLP half of voice recognition will be worthless since whatever phonemes or words the acoustic side outputs will be nonsensical. But if you just mean a time-series deep learning network, well go for it, could be interesting.